# Anyone have some available scripts ready to transform xml attributes into xml tags?

Tags: javascript, xml, converters

For example I have the following:

```
<Menu>
  <Item name="Favorite" type="Eats">
    <Item name = "Food" type="Tasty">
      <Item name="pizza" type="cheese">
      <Item name="Chicken" type="fried">
    </Item>
  </Item>
</Menu>
```

into the following:

```
<Menu>
  <Item>
    <name>Favorite</name>
    <type>Eats</type>
    <Item>
      <name>Food</name>
      <type>Tasty</type>
      <Item> <name>Pizza</name>   <type>Cheese</type> </Item>
      <Item> <name>Chicken</name> <type>Crispy</type> </Item>
    </Item>
  </Item>
</Menu>
```

Comment: No. Don't be lazy, and write some code.

Comment: @MattBall, Hey thanks for your comment. Not being lazy, just trying to be more efficient. I started using xml file for data, then decided its better to use json, so now I'm trying to convert xml to json. I found a converter online, but in order to use it correctly, I need to convert the attributes into tags.

Comment: @user814628: It's 12 hours ago, I'd say, you should have done that already, so please answer your own question, that is highly recommended.

Comment: @hakre, yes but unfortunately this thread is closed. I'm not sure why because I believe it follows guidelines. Whatever.

Comment: if you have an answer, we can vote to re-open your question. I won't stand in the way for that. Let me know.